# Text will not print in the Python interpreter from these two methods I made

Tags: python

I want to call either method (getPerimeter | getArea) and return the answer depending on the input provided.

```
#!usr/bin/python

def getPerimeter(x, y):
    answer = (2 * x) + (2 * y)
    return string(answer)  **This will not return anything in my terminal**
def getArea(x, y):  
    answer = x * y 
    return string(answer)   **This also will not return anything in my terminal**

reply = raw_input("Do you want to find the area or the perimeter? ")

if reply == "area":
    response1 = raw_input("What is the length ?: ")
    response2 = raw_input("What is the width ?: ")
    response1Int = int(response1)
    response2Int = int(response2)
    getArea(response1Int, response2Int)
else:
    response3 = raw_input("What is the length ?: ")
    response4 = raw_input("What is the width ?: ")
    response3Int = int(response3)
    response4Int = int(response4)
    getPerimeter(response3Int, response4Int)
```

Comment: `print getArea(response1Int, response2Int)`
or
`print getPerimeter(response3Int, response4Int)`

Answer (score 3):

[`return`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) returns, it doesn't [`print`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement).

Answer (score 2):

Returning something from a function doesn't *print* it to the screen. Try `print(getArea(response1Int, response2Int))` and `print(getPerimeter(response1Int, response2Int))`

Also, `string` is not a function.